# Sharing files between Vista and a Wubi Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, file-sharing, wubi

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most certainly is! Ubuntu now has mature support for NTFS, so you can use it without all your files being eaten. Follow the [How To Enable NTFS Write Support (ntfs-3g) On Ubuntu Feisty Fawn](http://www.howtoforge.com/ntfs_3g_ubuntu_feisty) from HowtoForge for a detailed guide on enabling this.

Comment: After all, the Wubi system is just a loopmounted disk image, stored on a NTFS partition.

Comment: Yeah, but I tend to ignore things like that. It confuses me… :P

Answer (score 0):

On the installs I have used it started with adding ntfs support
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/widows-ntfs-partitions-readwrite-support-made-easy-in-ubuntu-feisty.html